# Exception pragmatic writing a file

Tags: java

I have written a method which writes an object to file.
I used generics so also an object derived from Object can be written (I could also accept a parameter of type Object, but this to be more clear).

```
public static <T extends Object> void write(T item,String path) 
throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
{
    ObjectOutputStream os;
    Object obj=item;
    os=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
    os.writeObject(obj);
    os.close();
}
```

So the doubt is about the pragmatic: is correct to leave the exceptions go without handling them?because I have also written a second version of the method:

```
public static <T extends Object> void nothrow_write(T item,String path) 
{
    ObjectOutputStream os;
    Object obj=item;
    try
    {
        os=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        os.writeObject(obj);
        os.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);      
    }
}
```

Which method is more pragmatically correct?
The problem of the first one is that if the exception is thrown, the stream remains opened.

Comment: Using generics like this doesn't make any sense to me. How is that more clear than `void write(Object,String)`?

Comment: _Yes, you're right.I speciefied I used generics only to be more clear, it could also accept an Object._

Comment: The stream remains open on exception in the second one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void write(Object item, String path) 
  throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
  ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
  try {
    os.writeObject(obj);
  } finally {
    os.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a finally block to ensure the stream is closed whilst still throwing the exceptions if you wish:

```
public static <T extends Object> void myMethod(T item,String path) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException
{
    ObjectOutputStream os;
    Object obj=item;
    try
    {
        os=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        os.writeObject(obj);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        throw e; // Perhaps log the error before throwing
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        throw e; // Perhaps log the error before throwing
    }
    finally 
    {
         // Close stream here
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just move os.close() from try to finally?

Comment: Updated...I just copy-pasted his example and missed that

Answer (score 1):

The first version is wrong.  As you noted, it's a resource leak waiting to happen:

```
public static  void write() throws Exception
{
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
    os.writeObject(obj);
    os.close();
}
```

The second version is an improvement - at least you're doing a close ().

Other options include:

1) Close the file and re-throw the exception back to the caller

2) Use a "finally" clause:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

'Hope that helps...

Comment: Is a `finally block` still better practice than the `try-with-resources` block?

Comment: try-with-resources is in Java 7 only.  That might be fine for you.  But most of the world is still on Java 6 (and older).  And now that Oracle has taken over Java, it's unclear how quickly Java 7 adoption will occur...  IMHO...